# How to handle the case that the progeam needs to exit before an async void event handler finishes?

Tags: c#

According to MSDN the event handler is the only acceptable usage for async void. But how to handle the case that the progeam needs to exit before an async void event handler finishes?

I tried a WPF app it seems the program just exit without executing any code after the await line in the async event handler. That means probably some clean-up codes are bypassed and the system could be in invalid state.

I have googled a lot but never seen any comment saying "Don't use async event handler if there's any clean-up needed" or similar. Is this a very basic implication that anyone has already known?

Forgive me if this is a stupid question because I'm a newbie to C# world.

Comment: not stupid at all, but might have an answer already. could you include some code with your question, so we can see what you're actually attempting? what is raising the event? what is going on on the main thread in the mean time?

Comment: @dlatikay Thanks a lot for your quick answer. It's a general question so I don't have my code yet. I used this example https://github.com/mithunvp/AsyncAwaitDemoApp
The example is from http://www.mithunvp.com/building-responsive-ui-using-async-await-csharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe [Window.Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=netframework-4.7) event and set `e.Cancel` to `true` if async event handler is running.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //Flag indicating async operation is in progress
    private bool m_EventHandlerIsRunning = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Subscribe this method to MainWindow's Closing event
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Forbid MainWindow to close, if async event handler is running
        e.Cancel = m_EventHandlerIsRunning;
    }

    // You will have to include following in all async event handlers
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Forbid MainWindow to be closed
            m_EventHandlerIsRunning = true;

            // Do something async 
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Let MainWindow to be closed
            m_EventHandlerIsRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But your application must be able to recover from such situations (where clean-up code is not executed) anyway, because there is no way for you to prevent OS crash or power outage, that can occur at anytime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be an acceptable solution.
So can I say this is something that must be considered instead of ignored? MSDN should mention this in the async document.